Draw a Möbius trip with tangent vectors
So, I have been trying to illustrate the fact that the Möbius band doesn't have a non-vanishing normal vector space
I was trying to replicate this kind of thing : https://www.geogebra.org/m/tk3yjgva
Here is my latex code :
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} % Assure-toi que tu utilises la version appropriée

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=25mm,
    right=25mm,
    top=10mm,
    bottom=15mm,
}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newenvironment{statement}[2][Statement]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}

\begin{document}
 


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    hide axis,
    view = {40}{40}
    ]
    \addplot3 [
    surf,
    colormap={blackwhite}{gray(0cm)=(1); gray(1cm)=(0.5)},
    shader     = faceted interp,opacity = 0.7,
    samples    = 40,
    samples y  = 4,
    z buffer   = sort,
    domain     = 0:360,
    y domain   =-0.5:0.5
    ] (
    {(1+0.5*y*cos(x/2)))*cos(x)},
    {(1+0.5*y*cos(x/2)))*sin(x)},
    {0.5*y*sin(x/2) +1 }
    );

    % Draw the orange circle
    \addplot3 [
    samples=50,
    domain=-145:180,
    samples y=0,
    thick,
    color=orange
    ] (
    {cos(x)},
    {sin(x)},
    {1}
    );
    
    % Add tangent vectors that rotate as they follow the twist of the Möbius strip
    \addplot3 [
    quiver={
        u={cos(x/2)*cos(x)},  % Tangent vector with twisting effect
        v={cos(x/2)*sin(x)},  % Tangent vector with twisting effect
        w={sin(x/2)},         % Vertical component from the Möbius strip's twist
        scale arrows=0.2,     % Adjust size of arrows
    },
    samples=15, % Number of arrows
    domain=-145:180,
    -stealth,  % Arrow style
    color=blue, % Color of the tangent vectors
    ] (
    {cos(x)},
    {sin(x)},
    {1}
    );
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


As you can see, it is quite far from  my goal.
I would like to have all the normal vectors on the orange circle juste like the Geogebra example. I don't need multiple colours and 2 directions of vectors. One colour and one direction will suffice. I hope that you I am being clear and apologise in advance if it is not the case. Thank you all in advance for your help.
